# GLSL C style numeric cast

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am experiencing the following issue.I have two shaders (completely unrelated) which do casts to int and to float but in a different manner.

Cast example from Shader #1 (int to float):

```
 color = vec4(float(fragment_count) / float(MAX_FRAGMENTS));
```

Cast example from Shader #2 (float to int):

```
  int abNumFrag=(int)imageLoad(abufferCounterImg, coords).r;
```

The first shader compiles fine but the second is thrown an error:

**"OpenGL doesn't allow C-syle casts"**

Unless I enable the extension : #extension GL_NV_gpu_shader5 : enable

Isn't  (int)someFloat  the same as casting int(someFloat) ?

Answer (score 7):

The error message speaks for itself: the OpenGL Shading Language does not use C-style casts. It's not ***C*** with stuff; it's a separate language that looks kinda like C. But it doesn't use C-style cast syntax.

Enabling GL_NV_gpu_shader5 allows you to do it because NVIDIA likes taking liberties with the OpenGL specification once you declare your shader to be NVIDIA-specific like that. It's not actually a function of the [NV_gpu_shader5 extension specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/gpu_shader5.txt).

Answer (score 3):

In effect, but not in name.  GLSL casting is done by invoking constructors directly, not allowing typecasting in a C-like sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
int abNumFrag=int(imageLoad(abufferCounterImg, coords).r);
```

The same with float.